# How to remove all .NET SDKs installed by Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sdk

Upgrading from VS 2019 16.6 to 16.11 installed a the .NET 5 SDK, but also kept the old .NET 3.1 SDK.

There is no option to uninstall the old one from the VS Installer UI.
The [uninstall-tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows) does not detect the 3.1 because it was installed with Visual Studio.

Any ideas how to proceed safely with the safe removal of 3.1 SDK?

Comment: Have you tried by "add or remove programs" windows tool?

Comment: Yes, but I receive an error that the installation is managed by VS. And if I check/uncheck the .NET SDK in the VS Installer app, only the 5.0 SDK gets installed/uninstalled.